# Cgi programming in C, calling system() from my cgi program.

Tags: c, cgi, system

I've had a CGI program that I wrote in C and have used for some 20 years, and for the first time in a long time, I'm running in Windows, specifically windows 10, and I can't get a system() call to execute from the CGI program.   It seems like the system call is just ignored and doesn't create my output on the server side that I expect.
The CGI program is called from a form and using sprintf makes up the html page response into a giant buffer (szbuffer) and then prints to stdout which in the apache world goes back to the client.   Here is the routine that outputs the built up html page to the user:

```
    /** Print the CGI response header, required for all HTML output. **/
    /** Note the extra \n, to send the blank line.                  **/
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n") ;

    printf("%s\n<!--JL 7/12/01 11:00am -->\n",szBuffer); 
    free ( szBuffer);
```

Now this has worked fine for years, but in this version I wanted to run some system calls to search a csv file and create an answer set to be read with an fopen().  The way I've done this in linux is to just run commands using the system() command:

```
         getvaluecgivar(szcustomer_chain, "cust_field3", globals); 
         getvaluecgivar(szcustomer_id, "cust_field4", globals); 

         //sprintf(szdoscommand,"./awklookup_customer_id.bat %s %s "
         sprintf(szdoscommand,"awklookup_customer_id.bat %s %s"
    ,szcustomer_chain
    ,szcustomer_id
    ); 

          system(szdoscommand);
          system("cat lunch.trace >hw.lis");
          system("cat lunch.trace >/temp/hwt.lis");

          sprintf(szTempstring,"system command:%s: return code=%d\n"
      ,szdoscommand
      ,return_from_system_call
              );
        strcat(szBuffer, szTempstring); 

         } // then lookup by customer id
```

for reasons I need explaining and fixing, it appears as if the system() call (all three of them) never execute. The two "cat lunch.trace" system calls were just a test to see if I could get ANY system call to run and those commands also seem to fail.   Now I know I've done this on Linux without any issue before:

```
        FILE * tfile;

        system( "cat /tmp/relaystatus20*.txt >/tmp/rs20all.txt"); 

        tfile = fopen( "/tmp/rs20all.txt" , "r");
        if (tfile) {
            strcat(szBuffer, "<pre>"); 
                while(!feof(tfile)) {
```

and this creates the file rs20all.txt in the /tmp directory.

Is there something special I have to do on Windows?  I did capture the return code from the awklookup_customer_id.bat and it was 127.

Here is awklookup_customer_id.bat, it runs fine from either the dos prompt cmd.exe or a cygwin64 terminal:

```
  call \jon\bat\local >t.lis
  rem echo %1%, %2%
  set arg1=%1%
  set arg2=%2%

  gawk -F',' '{ if($3==%arg1%)  print $0 }' t5_clean_customer.csv >awk01.lis
  gawk -F',' '{ if($4==%arg2%)  print $0 }' awk01.lis >awk02.lis
  \jon\bat\grep.exe -nf awk02.lis t5_clean_customer.csv >awk03.lis
  cat awk03.lis|wc -l >awk03_c.lis
  set LINE_COUNT=0
  set /p LINE_COUNT=<awk03_c.lis
  cut -d: -f1 awk03.lis >awk03_ln.lis
  set LINE_NUMBER=0
  set /p LINE_NUMBER=<awk03_ln.lis
  SET /A Result = %LINE_COUNT% * 10000000 + %LINE_NUMBER%
  echo number of lines that match :%LINE_COUNT% line number: %LINE_NUMBER%
  rem pause
  exit  %Result%
```

I'm running Apache 2.4,  here are the environment variables that the cgi program gets:

```
  Print_environ::
  [HTTP_HOST=localhost]
  [HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive]
  [CONTENT_LENGTH=380]
  [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=max-age=0]
  [HTTP_ORIGIN=http://localhost]
  [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS=1]
  [CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
  [HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36]
  [HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8]
  [HTTP_REFERER=http://localhost/cgi-bin/bf_customer.cgi]
  [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate, br]
  [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US,en;q=0.9]
  [PATH=/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.dnx/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/2Printer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/MATLAB Runtime/v93/runtime/win64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Pico Technology/PicoScope6:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA/WinNT/Bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/IVI Foundation/VISA/Win64/Bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/jleslie/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps]
  [SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows]
  [COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe]
  [PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC]
  [WINDIR=C:\Windows]
  [SERVER_SIGNATURE=]
  [SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.4.23 (Win64)]
  [SERVER_NAME=localhost]
  [SERVER_ADDR=::1]
  [SERVER_PORT=80]
  [REMOTE_ADDR=::1]
  [DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:/jon/programs/Apache24/htdocs]
  [REQUEST_SCHEME=http]
  [CONTEXT_PREFIX=/cgi-bin/]
  [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT=c:/jon/programs/Apache24/cgi-bin/]
  [SERVER_ADMIN=admin@example.com]
  [SCRIPT_FILENAME=C:/jon/programs/Apache24/cgi-bin/bf_customer.cgi]
  [REMOTE_PORT=52945]
  [GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1]
  [SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1]
  [REQUEST_METHOD=POST]
  [QUERY_STRING=]
  [REQUEST_URI=/cgi-bin/bf_customer.cgi]
  [SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/bf_customer.cgi]
  [TERM=cygwin]
  [HOME=/home/jleslie]
  cgi vars:
  [colora] = [maroon]
  [cust_field1] = []
  [cust_field2] = []
  [cust_field3] = [0]
  [cust_field4] = [16]
```

Comment: It gets a bit tricky mixing cygwin and batch files, but a couple of things to try, then add to the question maybe. What is the user that is running Apache? I don't see where `return_from_system_call` is populated. You could try using the full path to `awklookup_customer_id.bat` or temporarily putting the batch file (or a simpler one) in a folder that's already on the path.  Try something other than `cat`first off - that's cygwin, so marginally less reliable on Windows - maybe `cmd /c echo %cd%`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  the answer has to do with httpd.conf.   I needed to tell apache that its ok to run .bat file:

```
   # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
   #
   #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
   AddHandler cgi-script .bat # add .exe if you wish
   Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks
```

sorry about the confusion with the return_from_system_call, I was adding and removing it so often I posted a version of the code where it wasn't set.  This is the final code section that works:

```
         getvaluecgivar(szcustomer_chain, "cust_field3", globals); 
         getvaluecgivar(szcustomer_id, "cust_field4", globals); 

         sprintf(szdoscommand,"awklookup_customer_id.bat %s %s"
                 ,szcustomer_chain
                 ,szcustomer_id
                 ); 

          return_from_system_call =system(szdoscommand);

          sprintf(szTempstring,"system command:%s: return code=%d\n"
                  ,szdoscommand
                  ,return_from_system_call
                  );
          strcat(szBuffer, szTempstring);
```

Comment: sorry about the confustion with the return_from_system_call. I had been moving, adding, and removing it I didn't post a version of my code where I used it.  here is the final version that works nicely: